# how to give box-shadow in mail

Tags: html, css

I want to create my own mail by html code.

Now I have written the following code

```
<table style="margin:auto;box-shadow:0 0 11px #090909">
</table>
```

The properties are working properly but the effect of boxshadow is not working in gmail and yahoo but it works properly in other company domain

Comment: box-shadow are not supported on gmail/yahoo-mail as was said on [this guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css)

Comment: Then is there any other way give shadow in email?

Answer (score 9):

Thats how we did this when no CSS3 was around:

```
  <div class="shadow" style="width:150px">
    <div class="overlay">
      <p>BoxShadows 90s style.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.overlay {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
.shadow {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.shadow .overlay {
  bottom: 4px;
  position: relative;
  right: 4px;
}
```

Works by underlaying the content with a slightly displaced gray div.

Look here for the not so fancy result. [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/KiCn1RswFkxBu3H4hezk?p=preview)

Another way would be to wrap your table in a table where the outer cells have 2 stretched half transparent pngs and 1 corner png as background. Looks far better, but since most email clients don't show images by default, I would stick to the good old browser safe suggestion with an overlay div.

Comment: That's a great solution and should work in all clients.

Comment: Is there a way to make this shadow blurry?

Comment: position property is not supported in Gmail and other clients

Answer (score 7):

It is only supported in a [few email clients.](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) You are better off using images if you want 100% support.

Answer (score -14):

```
<table style="margin:auto;box-shadow:0 0 11px #090909;">
```

You forgot to add ; check with that if that is the issue.

Comment: there is no need of ; at the end

Comment: a trailing `;` is not necessary - the OP syntax is correct

Comment: Hey, pal, you know you can delete this answer anytime, and you will recover the lost reputation. Don't feel ashamed, all of us have posted a wrong answer, we're human coders after all.